# Lightbox2 not working on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: lightbox2

I cannot get Lightbox 2 to work on Internet Explorer, but it is fine on Chrome and Firefox.  I have read online solutions, so thought it may be because I was using an older version, so set up a test page with the latest version and linked to lightbox-plus-jquery.js instead of lightbox.js as instructed, but still isn't working.  Here is the test page www.graffitisolutions.co.nz/test.  I would be so grateful if someone could help me solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Your page is using a meta tag in the head to switch to Internet Explorer 8 compatibility mode:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
```

The Lightbox2 script *does* support Internet Explorer 8, but jQuery 2.x *does not*. The lightbox-plus-jquery.js file includes jQuery v2.x and supports IE 9+. You can grab jQuery 1.x from the jQuery homepage if you want IE8 support and use it with lightbox.js. Details on Lightbox browser support:
http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/#browser-support

Sidenote: The page you linked is showing an error trying to load prototype.js and scriptaculous.js. There are also many HTML validation errors that are worth investigating: https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.graffitisolutions.co.nz%2Ftest%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0